# Convert list of years into another series of numbers R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a series of years 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014. I want to convert them into a series 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6+ in R. The most recent year is number one, and I want anything that's 6 or more years ago to be grouped into one item. This will then be stored as a column in the data with a `mutate` clause.

I have already calculated the latest year and saved it as a variable, `Latest_Yr`.

```
Latest_Yr <- data %>%
  (summarise(max(Full_year))

data %>%
  mutate(Yr_Sqnce = ((Latest_Yr - Full_year) + 1)) %>%
  ifelse(select_data$Yr_Sqnce <6, Yr_Sqnce, "6+")
```

I try to run the mutate but get

```
Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, , ) : 
  Column 7 ['Yr_Sqnce'] is a data.frame or data.table; malformed data.table.
```

I've tried `as.integer` in front of the `summarise` and just the `max()`, but they're giving an error. So, how do I make it store the number as an integer, not a table, so I can calculate my list?

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data, 10 rows with at least 7 years should be plenty.

Comment: It's strange you're getting `data.table` errors since you're using `dplyr`. Are you intentionally use `data.table`?

Comment: You do have a few problems that jump out just from looking at the code. `summarise` returns a data frame (or tibble), so `Latest_Yr` is a data frame, but you're trying to use it like a vector. You can `%>% pull` the column you want out. And similarly `mutate` returns a data frame, and you pipe that data frame into `ifelse`, but `ifelse` works on vectors, not data frames--you should keep the `ifelse()` inside `mutate()`.

Comment: `pmin(max(x) - x + 1, 6)` to simply represent "6+" as 6, and avoid coercion to character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
ifelse(select_data$Yr_Sqnce <6, select_data$Yr_Sqnce, "6+")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure what `data` looks like, so I just created a minimal example here. You don't need to get the `max` ahead of time; you can just use `max` in a `mutate` statement to calculate the new numbers. Then, I used an `ifelse` inside of `mutate` to replace the 6+ values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(group = (max(year) - year)+1), 
         group = ifelse(group >= 6, "6+", group))
```

**Output**

```
  year group
1 2021     1
2 2020     2
3 2019     3
4 2018     4
5 2017     5
6 2016    6+
7 2015    6+
8 2014    6+
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(year = c(
    2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014
  )),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Latest_Yr <- max(select_data$Full_year)

select_data <- select_data %>%
  mutate(Yr_Sqnce = (((Latest_Yr - Full_year) + 1))) %>%
  mutate(Yr_Sqnce = ifelse(Yr_Sqnce <6, Yr_Sqnce, "6+"))
```

With a bit of help from the comments above regarding storing the latest year, and Stefan's answer, I have managed to get it working. I had to put the second mutate in as otherwise my R studio/dplyr was creating another column with the ifelse code as the column heading, not tweaking the Yr_Sqnce. As the output of this column is an input into another bit of code, I need a sensible variable name.